# Ajax : Call undefined function plugin_function() ... can't call any plugin function

Tags: plugins, functions, ajax

I use a Ajax query to show some content, but I can't use any of my plugins functions.

Javascript :

```
$('#load_more').click(function() {
    var data = {
        action: 'load_more',
        id: $("input#id").val()
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        $("#content").append(response);
    });
});
```

PHP in functions.php :

```
function load_more(){
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);

    if(!isset($id) or !is_numeric($id)){
        echo "Error";}
    else {
        $works = plugin_function($id);
        wordpress_function_works($id, $works);}
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');
```

The Ajax works fine, it can call & work with any of my wordperss functions. But when I call a plugin function, it returns an error `Call undefined function plugin_function() line...`

PS: `ajaxurl = /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: Is your plugin a class?

Comment: Yes it is. BTW I can call my plugin function in my theme pages

Comment: Do you have helper functions? That is not correct syntax for access class methods.

Comment: The function i'm trying to call is outside of the plugin class. It's just a function.

Comment: The function itself is a helper that access the plugin class. What is weird is that I can't even call this function, it's just like the plugin wasn't loaded...

Comment: I have no trouble accessing plugin functions via the AJAX API. Something has to be peculiar about your setup. I notice you are using `$` most of the time and `jQuery` once. That is odd. Are you sure the Javascript works? Are your variables being passed correctly?

Comment: Is your plugin loading file with that function definition depending on any condition?